# Bot throwing 502 Bad Gateway on test

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've successfully deployed bot in the past, and I never had to deal with a problem like this. Now all of the sudden the second bot that I've developed is giving me this error 502 bad gateway. Now I even dumb it down to just the scaffold that VS2017 creates when you create from the template just to see if there's any problem but even that one is no dice.

Things I tried.
ngRok; when I did debug it, it goes to rootdialog() then it stops there and I get the bad gateway 502.

I also tried, removing and creating new resources and services and recreating all that's in the manual. Am I missing something?

Thank you all.
Regards

Comment: Does your previous bot still function properly and allow deployments? This would help to see if its an account-wide issue or perhaps a problem with this specific instance. If it seems to be account-wide, it might be better to follow up on this by raising an issue in the [Botbuilder repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) or through the azure portal itself.

Comment: yes it does @MarkB

Answer (score 1):

> my second bot that I've developed is giving me this error 502 bad gateway.

In [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#what-causes-the-direct-line-30-service-to-respond-with-http-status-code-502-bad-gateway), we can find that this error (HTTP status code 502 "Bad Gateway") indicates that either the bot returned an error or the request timed out. So please make sure your bot application can work fine on local and no task takes long time to retuen result in your bot application code.

If possible, you can try to create new web app bot (and specify a **new** App Service plan), and then you can upgrade the Bot Builder SDK for your bot application and publish it to that corresponding app service to check if your bot application can work with the new bot service.

Besides, sometimes [the issue with Azure bot service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868674/bot-framework-direct-line-502-error/50869617#50869617) might cause same error, if you are sure that your bot application code can work without error and configure [bot Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) and Application Settings correctly, but your bot on Azure still not work as expected, you can try to [create a support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to report it.

***Note:***

When you deploy the bot application to Azure, you can check "*Remove additional files at destination*" option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fei, appreciate the reply, but I've done everything you have suggested, nothing works, I've deleted and created a new plan and service and deployed the most basic bot, that works on my local machine, but once deployed I still get the gateway error.

Comment: Hi Fei. Is there a way to catch this error on the client side? I am using directline channel and doing something like- `BotChat.App({
  botConnection: botConnection,
   }, document.getElementById('chatBot'));`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue, for those who might encounter the same, when your bot used to work before March 2018 and now it's throwing the 502 error and the 405 (CORS), you have to manage a custom state now, you can't just use Microsoft temporary state it's only good for local testing.

1. Create a new storage account (table storage)
2. Add the following to your Global.asax

> ```
> Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder => {
>                 builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
>                 var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
>
>                 builder.Register(c => store)
>                 .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
>                 .AsSelf()
>                 .SingleInstance();
>
>
>             });
> ```

And don't forget to add the connection string on your config files.